# ¿Cómo enviar una String a una impresora?

Tags: java, imprimir

Intento imprimir en una impresora de Tiquets EPSON TM-T20, no hay opción para establecer la codificación pero si la hoja de caracteres, en mi caso PC858.
He comprobado la hoja de carácteres de la impresora y estan allí.

**Intento 1:** No me imprime los *acentos* ni el símbolo *€*:

```
public static void imprimir(){

 byte[] bytes = new String("Estó ès una pruebà \r\n Hola qu€ tal").getBytes();      
 PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
 DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
 DocPrintJob pj = service.createPrintJob();
 Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);
 pj.print(doc, null);
}
```

Salida:

```
Est├│ ├¿s una prueb├á
Hola quÔé¼ tal
```

**Intento 2**: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: data is not of declared type`

```
public static void imprimir(){
 char[] bytes = new String("Estó ès una pruebà \r\n "
            + "Hola qu€ tal").toCharArray();        
     PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
     DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;//TEXT_PLAIN_UTF_8 tampoco
     DocPrintJob pj = service.createPrintJob();
     Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);
     pj.print(doc, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución:
char[] no es compatible con la impresora. Para saber que tipos son compatibles usar:

```
Arrays.stream(service.getSupportedDocFlavors()).forEach(f->System.out.println(f.getMediaType()+":"+f.getMimeType()+":"+f.getRepresentationClassName()));
```

Tambien se puede usar unicode, pero como no encontré forma de hacerlo funcionar, utilizo directamente el charset(hoja de carácteres) cp858.

```
 public static void print(){
    byte[] bytes = new String("Estó ès una pruebà \r\n Hola qu€ tal").getBytes(Charset.forName("Cp858"));
    PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;
    DocPrintJob pj = service.createPrintJob();
    Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(bytes, flavor, null);
    pj.print(doc, null);
}
```

Comment: Ojo, eso solo funciona en Java 8 y superiores.